# npm update fails for Vue 2 project, created with vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I've created a Vue 2 project with `vue-cli` and tried to run `npm update`.
Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
{
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test-vue@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.12
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"~2.6.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"3.0.7" from @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc
npm ERR!   peerOptional @vue/compiler-sfc@"^3.0.0-beta.14" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-service@"~4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@vue/cli-plugin-babel)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/turf": "^6.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet-geodesy": "^0.2.1",
    "vue": "~2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "~3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "~2.6.11"
  }
}
```

I thought the `~` in the `package.json` should prevent from upgrading to Vue 3?

You help is appreciated!

**EDIT: Tried as suggest with ncu -u**

```
PS E:\projects\test-vue> ncu -u
Upgrading E:\projects\test-vue\package.json
[====================] 20/20 100%
 core-js                  ^3.6.5  →   ^3.9.1
 vue                     ~2.6.11  →  ~2.6.12
 vue-router               ~3.2.0  →   ~3.5.1
 @vue/cli-plugin-babel    ~4.5.0  →  ~4.5.11
 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint   ~4.5.0  →  ~4.5.11
 @vue/cli-plugin-router   ~4.5.0  →  ~4.5.11
 @vue/cli-service         ~4.5.0  →  ~4.5.11
 eslint                   ^6.7.2  →  ^7.21.0
 eslint-plugin-prettier   ^3.1.3  →   ^3.3.1
 eslint-plugin-vue        ^6.2.2  →   ^7.7.0
 prettier                ^1.19.1  →   ^2.2.1
 sass                    ^1.26.5  →  ^1.32.8
 sass-loader              ^8.0.2  →  ^11.0.1
 vue-template-compiler   ~2.6.11  →  ~2.6.12

Run npm install to install new versions.

PS E:\projects\test-vue> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.24.3
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.8.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^1.7.1" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!       dev @vue/cli-service@"~4.5.11" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...)
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=4.0.0" from @vue/preload-webpack-plugin@1.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/preload-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     @vue/preload-webpack-plugin@"^1.1.0" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!       dev @vue/cli-service@"~4.5.11" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...)
npm ERR!   8 more (babel-loader, copy-webpack-plugin, css-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@1.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin
npm ERR!   @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@"^1.0.5" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-service@"~4.5.11" from the root project
npm ERR!     4 more (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-06T19_52_21_583Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I guess you have updated one your dependencies to a version which requires Vue 3. Find which one is it and downgrade it back...

Comment: Delete your node_modules and package.lock file then run npm i --legacy-peer-deps hope its work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There was an issue with some dependencies.
I finally worked this out by creating a new project with vue-cli and copying that package.json there.

**Edit:**
You have to make sure that you use compatible versions of all dependencies. - The best way to do this is to generate a project with vue-cli to get compatible versions.

**Long story short: don't mess with the dependencies**

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try to `npm i -g npm-check-updates` then in the root folder try to execute `ncu -u` this will update your dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies

Comment: Really appreciate your help, Jay!

Unfortuntately, I'm getting new errors regarding webpack. - I thought it should be integrated into vue-cli, no?